# Integrating N2CMS with existing ASP.Net Website

Tags: asp.net

We need to select a CMS for our company's website which will allow the designers to make changes to the pages, add pages, view and publish them.
We r using Visual Studio 2010 for web development and includes Global.asax, Masterpages, User-/Custom-Controls, Security (FormsAuthentication, custom Membership-/RoleProvider). W ehave SQL server 2008 for the DB. 
I have looked into various CMS like Sitefinity,N2CMS, Umbraco, DotNetnuke. We kinda liked playing with the demo of N2CMS. We don't want to start developing the site from scratch. We want to integrate some CMS into our application for the designers to use. However, I can't find any helpful documentation regarding the integration. Everyone starts talking building from sctrach. The documentation for N2CMS seems so outdated.

If anyone can guide me how to set a CMS into exsiting application, I will really appreciate it.

Thanks